# Objective-c app crash only when exported (ad-hoc or on AppStore) in correspondence of dispatch_async

Tags: ios, objective-c, dispatch-async

I'm experiencing a crash on an iOS app, but only when it is archived and exported (ad-hoc or on AppStore). The develop version does not have any problem.

The crash is in correspondence of a dispatch_async on the main queue. In particular:

```c
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    ...
            [self.view hideToastActivity];
            self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            if (self.delegate != nil) {
            [self.delegate postFooObject:foo];
        }
    ...
    });
```

As you can see, the code block calls a delegate method, whose code is:

```c
- (void)postFooObject:(Foo *)foo {
        [self.view makeToastActivity:CSToastPositionCenter];
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        [[FooManager sharedManager] postFoo:&foo completition:^(BOOL success) {

            if (success) {
                [self.view hideToastActivity];
                self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

                [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
            }
}
```

The *postFooObject* delegate method contains a call to a REST endpoint, which returns successfully.

Since it is a production app, I  managed to print the log when the app is killed by means of iSO Console application. The following screenshot shows the device log at the moment of the crash:

[image]

The app process is identified by "indemni".

**Executing all the instructions contained in the dispatch block outside the dispatch_async itself instead was fine**.

Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Show real code and the crash log.

Comment: Question was edited

Answer (score 0):

The main queue should be used only for UI tasks, if u are making rest calls try to use a global queue and use the main just to update the UI components with the new data.

Are you testing the develop version on simulator or an iPhone? This could generate different responses to this code, but i think that change the queue should solve your problem! :)

Good luck!